# Trouble Writing a Basic String-Encryption Program in C - Indexing Character Arrays

Tags: c, pointers, char

I am a little stuck attempting to write a program which 'encrypts' a string, in C. The goal of the program is to allow a user to encrypt a string by entering a cypher which will be used to swap out letters in the original string, garbling it. My original program was much more complicated than this, with logic to handle parsing user-input cyphers and to maintain case (which all worked, shockingly!). However, the absolute basic problem that I cannot solve is that the string returned by my 'encryption' function is incorrect.

I have re-written another barebones version of the function to try and debug it; this was my naive version of the program, before I started to look up information:

```
// Barebones character swap for the encryption program
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define GET_CHARS_MAX 100

const char plainAlphabet[26]  = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm',
                                 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'};
const char prebakedCypher[26] = {'v', 'c', 'h', 'p', 'r', 'z', 'g', 'j', 'n', 't', 'l', 's', 'k',
                                 'f', 'b', 'd', 'q', 'w', 'a', 'x', 'e', 'u', 'y', 'm', 'o', 'i'};

int encryptString(char *encryptStr, int stringLength)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++)    // For each letter in the alphabet
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < stringLength; j++)    
        {
            if (encryptStr[j] == plainAlphabet[i]) // Find and replace that letter on each pass
            {
                encryptStr[j] = prebakedCypher[i];
            }
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    char *userString      = malloc(GET_CHARS_MAX);
    char *stringToEncrypt = malloc(GET_CHARS_MAX); 
    // Get user input into string
    printf("\n Enter a string, 100 characters long maximum: ");
        fgets(userString, GET_CHARS_MAX, stdin);
        int stringLength = strlen(userString) - 1;    // Remove null I think?

    // Make a copy of the input to encrypt
    strcpy(stringToEncrypt, userString);
        printf("\n Copied string: %s", stringToEncrypt);

    // Check that indexing the alphabet and cypher actually works
    // the way that you think it does
    printf("\n Alphabet element 1: %c \n Cypher element 1: %c", plainAlphabet[0], prebakedCypher[0]);
    printf("\n Alphabet element 't': %c \n Cypher element 't': %c", plainAlphabet[19], prebakedCypher[19]);

    // 'Encrypt' string and display result
    printf("\n Plaintext string: %s", userString);
        encryptString(stringToEncrypt, stringLength);
    printf("\n Encrypted string: %s", stringToEncrypt);

    return 0;
}
```

As you can see, the logic is very simple; if for each letter of the alphabet `(i)` we find that letter in our string `(j)`, replace it with the letter in the corresponding position from the cypher (i.e. 'a' should be replaced with 'v', etc. However, output was confusing:

```
 Enter a string, 100 characters long maximum: this is a string

 Copied string: this is a string

 Alphabet element 1: a
 Cypher element 1: v
 Alphabet element 't': t
 Cypher element 't': x
 Plaintext string: this is a string

 Encrypted string: mmfa fa u amoffg
```

I like to check as much as I can with `printf`; the character arrays seemed to index correctly, but aren't assigning properly in the `for-loops` (both 't' and 'h' are '*m*', 'a' is being assigned the character '*u*', and so on). 
I looked up how to index character arrays properly and found some posts directing me to make *an additional pointer to the start of the array*, and then do pointer arithmetic with the loop counter to deference the pointer on the element you need. My horrid attempt at this was:

```
int encryptString(char *encryptStr, int stringLength)
{
    char *cypherPointer = &prebakedCypher[0];

    for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++)    // For each letter in the alphabet
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < stringLength; j++)    
        {
            if (encryptStr[j] == plainAlphabet[i]) // Find and replace that letter on each pass
            {
                encryptStr[j] = (*cypherPointer) + i;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Which just produces garbage.

In the simple examples I found, people were just using `for-loops` to print out values from a character array using the `ptr`, to explain what they do/how they work.

I'm a beginner and have probably been staring at my original program too long now to determine what my problem is. Can someone explain where my logic has gone wrong, and if my initial naive indexing of the character array (which I understand to be a pointer to the element in `charArr[0]`) was on the right lines or not? Because fundamentally, I think my misunderstanding is what to do with the pointer to the character array(s) and how to index/assign to them correctly.

Thankyou!

Edit: I should mention that, since the string is garbled, I thought my program was working at first. I then tried `abcdef` to make sure the correct elements were being read from/replaced, and found the input wasn't what I expected, given how the `printf` statements seemed to index the `alphabet` and `cypher arrays`:

```
 Enter a string, 100 characters long maximum: abcdef

 Copied string: abcdef

 Alphabet element 1: a
 Cypher element 1: v
 Alphabet element 't': t
 Cypher element 't': x
 Plaintext string: abcdef

 Encrypted string: ummdoi
```

There are no repeat letters in the cypher so both 'b' and 'c' cannot be replaced ith '*m*'. We also know 'a' should be replaced with '*v*', not '*u*'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're replacing the string in-place, you check each character 26 times, and you  replace it between 1 and 26 times depending on the cypher and the starting character.

For instance, this is why both 'b' and 'c' become 'm' in your example:

- 'b' is replaced with 'c'.
- The next iteration, that 'c' is replaced with 'h'.
- 5 iterations later, that 'h' is replaced with 'j'.
- 2 iterations later, that 'j' is replaced with 't'.
- 10 iterations later, that 't' is replaced with 'x'.
- 4 iterations later, that 'x' is replaced for the last time with 'm'.

Instead, just check each character up to 26 times, and replace it exactly one time:

```
int encryptString(char *encryptStr, int stringLength)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < stringLength; i++)    // For each letter in input
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 26; j++)    
        {
            if (encryptStr[i] == plainAlphabet[j]) // Find and replace that letter 
            {
                encryptStr[i] = prebakedCypher[j];
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah, of course. My loops were doing a better encryption job than I thought, then!
I considered doing it the way you outlined at first, but thought it would take unnecessary passes since you're searching (potentially) the whole alphabet for each letter. I had attempted to replace each occurence of the letter on each pass. 
Get it working first optimise later!

Comment: @Rowan Sure, but you always have to search potentially for the whole alphabet for each letter. Best you can do is move onto the next letter as soon as you find a match.

Comment: Of course. Thanks again for spotting my daft problem immediately and adding to your breakdown of it! I'll be on the lookout for stuff like this in the future.